# how can i allow user to download an image in flex without making server call

Tags: apache-flex, image, download

I have a flex application showing a chart. I want to give user the functionality to download this chart as image. How can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This Adobe Cookbook entry](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Save_a_file_locally_with_Flash_Player_10-14426.html) can answer your question. And yes, your project should be targeted Flash Player 10.

Comment: i am not getting the save method. I am using flex3.5. Any idea y is it so?

Comment: It is Flex SDK independent. Just set Flash Player version to 10.0.0 in project settings.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the [ImageSnapshot](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/graphics/ImageSnapshot.html) class to take a 'pic' of the chart, then save it locally using [FileReference.save()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#save%28%29).